# extract from list and save to csv

Tags: r, list

I am struggling to do something that I know should be simple.

I have a list of dataframes like so:

```
a <- rep(1, 10)
b <- rep(3.6, 10)
foo1 <- cbind(a, b)

d <- rep(2, 8)
b <- rep(4.9, 8)
foo2 <- cbind(d, b)

data <- list(foo1, foo2)
```

I want to extract the 2nd column from each dataframe, either by indexing or by column name, and save to a csv file using write.table and with the same name as the dataframe.  I have tried a lot of things---for loops and `lapply` and `sapply`.

I get a variety of error messages, but mostly the following:

`In if (file == "") file <- stdout() else if (is.character(file)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

which I can't resolve.

I know I'm not indexing properly.  Help me please!

Comment: `lapply(data, function(x) x[,2,drop=FALSE])`

Comment: What's the code you tried that resulted in such an error?

Comment: Those are not dataframes.

Comment: ack.  Sorry on the fake data that's not df's.  The real data objects are dataframes!

Comment: @akrun  That would extract the columns.  But then how do I feed the results of lapply into individual csv's?  I tried a for loop and lapply again for that and couldn't get the indexing right.

Comment: @MrFlick  I deliberately didn't post all my failed tries b/c I think anything you guys come up with will be much cleaner than coercing my ugly code into something that works.

Comment: `lst <- lapply(data, function(x) x[,2,drop=FALSE]);  lapply(seq_along(lst), function(i) write.csv(lst[[i]], file=paste0('file', i, '.csv'))` or so

Comment: @akrun  Thanks! When I tried that method previously, I failed to use 'seq_along' so wasn't accessing 'lst' properly, and also didn't index lst properly in the write.table command.  Is there a way to bring along the original name of the dateframe when creating 'lst'?  Files are all called '1csv', '2csv', etc.

Comment: You can set the names of lst as the dataframe object names or alternatively use `mget()` to get the list element names as `dataframe` object names.

Comment: Sorry--my bad.  Had left off the 'file' part of file = paste0('file'. . . .)  I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop to iterate over the fields of `data`:

```
for (i in 1:length(data)) {
    col <- data[[i]][,2]
    fname <- paste("foo", i, ".csv", sep="")
    write.table(col,fname)
}
```

The `write.table` command will likely need a bit of tweaking, until you get the data in the format you want.

Comment: Thanks! I'd tried this method as well, and had it all correct except the way you indexed 'data' in the 2nd line of code.  I kept trying to just use [i] in variations without referencing 'data'. Now I've got two clean methods.